# Spring Boot application.properties value not populating and not reading

Tags: java, eclipse, spring, command-line, spring-boot

When I am configuring `-Dext.prop.dir` from eclipse Its run fine and and everything work. It runs on 8085 port and specified context `"DBService"`.

But when i am running jar generated using maven from command line it wont read application.properties it by default tomcat is starting on 8080 and i am not able to identify the context. Every things else works fine.

In eclipse I have supplied : VM argument as : `-Dext.prop.dir=E:/res/ -Dlog.name=D:/res/logback.xml`

My post and question looks similar and i have refer this [post already](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25764459/spring-boot-application-properties-value-not-populating) with that only i have refer application.properteis to configure custom context and port for spring boot application. I have refer this [link](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html) as well but i could not figured out what is the problem when I am running jar from command line.

Same vm argument i am putting as below :

```
java -Dext.prop.dir=D:/res/ -jar com.drd.db.services-1.0.0.M1-jar-with-dependencies.jar
```

And I have kept my application.properteis as D:/res/application.properteis.

Below is my application startup class and application.properties .

```
   package com.drd.application.configuration;
    import static com.drd.db.service.util.ServicesConstants.EXT_PROP_DIR;
    import static com.drd.db.service.util.ServicesConstants.LOG_BACK_XML_SYSTEM_PROPERTY;

    import org.slf4j.Logger;
    import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
    import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
    import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.EnableAutoConfiguration;
    import org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedServletContainerFactory;
    import org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.tomcat.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory;
    import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
    import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
    import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
    import org.springframework.context.annotation.PropertySource;
    import org.springframework.util.StringUtils;

    import com.drd.db.service.util.ServicesConstants;

    @ComponentScan(basePackages = { "com.drd.db" })
    @Configuration
    @PropertySource({"file:///${ext.prop.dir}application.properties"/*, "classpath:application.properties"*/})
    @EnableAutoConfiguration
    public class ApplicationRunner {


        private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ApplicationRunner.class);

        public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
            String extPropDir=System.getProperty(EXT_PROP_DIR);
            if(StringUtils.isEmpty(extPropDir)){
                LOG.warn("Could not resolve  PropertyvSource placeholder 'ext.prop.dir' in string value file:///${ext.prop.dire}application.properties");
                LOG.warn("Could not finnd {} System property Please specify valid path for it ",ServicesConstants.EXT_PROP_DIR);
                return;
            }
            String logbackXMLPath=System.getProperty(LOG_BACK_XML_SYSTEM_PROPERTY);
            if(StringUtils.isEmpty(logbackXMLPath)){
                LOG.info("Could not finnd {} System property for loading logback.xml Please specify valid path for it proper loaggin ", LOG_BACK_XML_SYSTEM_PROPERTY);
            }
            LOG.info("ApplicationRunner Spring boot application start from this class");
            SpringApplication.run(ApplicationRunner.class, args);

        }
        @Bean
        public EmbeddedServletContainerFactory servletContainer() {
            TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory factory = new TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory();
            return factory;
        }

    }
```

MY **applicaion.properties** :

```
#All application Label properties configure if any.
server.context-path=/DBService
server.port=8085
hibernate.prop.dir=D:/main/resources/
```

can any one know or share why those properties are not configured or read by spring when i am running from command line.

And one supersizing things is that if I am not putting application.properties in D:/res/ directory it throws excpeption as below , it mean it is reading that properties file:

**Exception :**

```
 2016-08-07 14:40:09.435  INFO 18168 --- [           main] .b.l.ClasspathLoggingApplicationListener : Application failed to start with classpath: [file:/D:com.drd.db.services-1.0.0.M1-jar-with-dependencies.jar]
2016-08-07 14:40:09.445 ERROR 18168 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application startup failed

org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Failed to load bean class: com.drd.application.configuration.ApplicationRunner; nested exception
 is java.io.FileNotFoundException: D:\htl-properties\application.properties (The system cannot find the file specified)
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.parse(ConfigurationClassParser.java:159)
...
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:944)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:933)
        at com.drd.application.configuration.ApplicationRunner.main(ApplicationRunner.java:45)
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: D:\res\application.properties (The system cannot find the file specified)
        at java.io.FileInputStream.open(Native Method)
        at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:146)
        at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:101)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.file.FileURLConnection.connect(FileURLConnection.java:90)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.file.FileURLConnection.getInputStream(FileURLConnection.java:188)
```

Comment: Looks like classpath issue.

Comment: I am not wring any specific class path as i am running generated from maven : com.drd.db.services-1.0.0.M1-jar-with-dependencies.jar.  it contain all jars and classes inside of it. So I dont need to supply any cp. 
And More over I am excluding application.properties in pom before creating jar. as below :

<excludes>
<exclude>**/application.properties</exclude>
<exclude>**/logback.xml</exclude>
</excludes>

Comment: Looks pretty clear: `java.io.FileNotFoundException: D:\htl-properties\application.properties (The system cannot find the file specified)`

Comment: hoping it is a typo... but in your Eclipse VM arguments you have the directory as `E:/` but in your java command you have it as `D:/`. Is that just  a typo?

Answer (score 2):

As far as I understood you would like to use variables which are in application.properties.

The way I follow is the below one ;

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-configuration-processor</artifactId>
   </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

After that insert following tag in your pom.xml as well

```
<build>
    <resources>
        <resource>
         <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
         <filtering>true</filtering>
         <includes>
            <include>**/*.properties</include>
         </includes>
         </resource>
    </resources>
</build>
```

then build your -jar with "mvn install" or "mvn clean install".

I hope it works.