# Spring Boot - @Value annotation doesn't work

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, annotations

I try to create mail service using SmtpAuthenticator. The component is started correctly but null values are in username and password fields. Why is it?

```
@Component
public class SmtpAuthenticator extends Authenticator {

    private static final Logger LOG = 
    LogManager.getLogger(SmtpAuthenticator.class.getSimpleName());

    @Value("${spring.mail.username}")
    private String username;
    @Value("${spring.mail.password}")
    private String password;

    public SmtpAuthenticator() {
        LOG.info(SmtpAuthenticator.class.getSimpleName() + " started...");
        LOG.debug("username=" + username);
    }

    @Override
    protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
        if (!StringUtils.isEmpty(username) && !StringUtils.isEmpty(password)) {
            LOG.debug("Username and password are correct...");
            return new PasswordAuthentication(username, password);
        }
    LOG.error("Not correct mail login data!");
    return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you defined the properties, `spring.mail.username` and `spring.mail.password` in your `application` properties/yaml file?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You guessed it right, the values will get injected only after the objects gets instantiated; because the spring container cannot set a property of something which doesn't exist yet. So while in constructer, those fields will still be null. One solution is, either

1. Switch to [constructer Injection](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/using-boot-spring-beans-and-dependency-injection.html) instead of setter Injection (YMMV, havnt tested your usecase)

**Or**

2. Replace the constructor with a method annotated with `@PostConstruct`. This method will be executed after the injection process.

### for example

```
@Component
public class SmtpAuthenticator extends Authenticator {
    private static final Logger LOG = 
    LogManager.getLogger(SmtpAuthenticator.class.getSimpleName());

    @Value("${spring.mail.username}")
    private String username;
    @Value("${spring.mail.password}")
    private String password;

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        LOG.info(SmtpAuthenticator.class.getSimpleName() + " started...");
        LOG.debug("username=" + username);
    }

    @Override
    protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
        if (!StringUtils.isEmpty(username) && !StringUtils.isEmpty(password)) {
            LOG.debug("Username and password are correct...");
            return new PasswordAuthentication(username, password);
        }
    LOG.error("Not correct mail login data!");
    return null;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Moved no argument constructor code to PostConstruct has done the trick for me. As it'll keep default bean loading workflow intact.

> Try this solution. https://stackoverflow.com/a/72547797/2002804