# @value in spring boot not giving value from application.properties

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I am trying to read value from application properties into a class annotated with

```
@Configuration
public class testClass {

  @Value("${com.x.y.z.dummy.name}")
  private String name;
```

once I run the code at a method in this class annotated with @Bean:

```
  @Bean
  public Helper helper(X x){
     System.out.println(this.name);
  }
```

Here the output is -> `${com.x.y.z.dummy.name}` instead of the value of `${com.x.y.z.dummy.name}` in the application.properties . I tried `@Autowired` and tried reading from environment variable too. Not sure what might be happening. Could anyone help with this?
Adding application.properties:

```
com.x.y.z.dummy.name=localhost
com.x.y.z.dummy.host=8888
```

Comment: If it's a Spring Boot application, it should normally work as described. If it's a Spring Core application, you should register a `PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer` as a bean post-processor (using static keywork)

Comment: Possible duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25764459/spring-boot-application-properties-value-not-populating

Comment: I have tried this it dint help @fatrixienicolie

Comment: Can you please add an example of your application.properties file? @ankitha

Comment: @dextertron_ added it , can you please check in the post

Comment: Can you try constructor injection: public testClass(@Value(""${com.x.y.z.dummy.name}"") String name) ?

Comment: Share your codebase through github for quicker solution

Comment: Can you put all code here? along with package name and main? This should normally works but depends on main method also, where you kept it for annotation scan

Comment: @Nico Van Belle thank you !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest to search in your project for a Bean that returns a `PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer`. That object could be configured to set a different prefix instead of "${". Doing so would result in the behavior that you are describing.

For example, creating this class I was able to reproduce your problem.

```java
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.support.PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer;

public class PrefixConfiguration {

    @Bean
    public static PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer configure(){
        PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer propertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer
                = new PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer();
        propertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer.setPlaceholderPrefix("%{");
        propertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer.setIgnoreUnresolvablePlaceholders(true);
        return propertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer;
    }
}
```

Your Bean could be different, and it could be there for a good reason, so don't blindly delete it without further investigation.

Comment: Thank you @gere , I don't see the PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer at all , I am facing this problem post an upgrade of a dependency which is a third party . Once I added the PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer it seems to be working fine

Comment: Then the `PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer` is configured inside the third party library in a way that changes the normal behavior. When you add it yourself, you are declaring it again, and doing so, make it work normally again.

Comment: Hey why should this -> static PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer configure() be a static method ? Could you please help me understand ?

Comment: Because the Spring docs suggest to do so: look here for the paragraph "BeanFactoryPostProcessor-returning @Bean methods":  https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/Bean.html it explains why and it uses a bean returning exactly the PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer as an example.